# Applying style for YouTube Popup Player's popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

I had used Youtube Popup player for video player in my webapplication, iam trying to change the styles of popup window..but iam not able to do it..i had found `cssClass property` for applying styles.. here is the link for youtube popup player..http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/

How can i resolve it..

Answer (score 1):

You can follow Arunkumar answer if you want to change the defaults of the plugin, so that you don't have to set the options everytime you want to initialize the plugin.

Or, you can set specific properties to each element with the plugin assigned, like this:

```
$(function () {
    var options = {
        fullscreen         : 0,
        color              : 'red',
        width              : 500,
        height             : 300,
        overlayOpacity     : 0.9
    };
    $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup(options);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCbGp/)

Or, instead of creating a variable options, you could just do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({
        fullscreen         : 0,
        color              : 'red',
        width              : 500,
        height             : 300,
        overlayOpacity     : 0.9
    };);
});
```

Hope I could make it more understandable to you!

Comment: thanks for replying silentw..i want to give a class to that youtube popup container and use that for styling..i know these properties , i had seen cssClass and idAttribute but dont know how to use them..

Comment: Probably that's only to style somehow the element that triggers the popup, not to style the popup itself. I may be wrong though...

Comment: After a quick look over the docs, `idAttribute` is to define whether the youtube link is in rel, href, name, etc attribute of the element. The `cssClass`, as described: `Attribute containing the CSS class to be assigned to the popup div`

Answer (score 0):

customize Popup using script

like

```
$(function () {
$.fn.YouTubePopup.defaults.fullscreen = 0;
$.fn.YouTubePopup.defaults.color1 = 'CCCCCC';
$.fn.YouTubePopup.defaults.width='500';
$.fn.YouTubePopup.defaults.height='300'; 
$.fn.YouTubePopup.defaults.overlayOpacity='0.5';
              });
```

You can able to change popup defaults above way.

Hope it helps:);